# How do I apply a margin to a React component without modifying the component itself?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a component I have been reusing throughout my code and now I want to add some spacing between the two components I am using. Using the inline styles, CSS modules, or even a global CSS file with a class name doesn't do anything and I don't want to modify the spacing of the component. I really don't want to modify the spacing from inside the component as it works well in other situations, I am using these components, it's only in this one situation I want to add a small margin between the component.

Here are the two components that I want to add spacing between.

```
      <EditTeamButtons showDelete={true} />
      <TeamView team={[]} cols={6} />
```

```
<EditTeamButtons showDelete={true} style={{marginBottom: '10px'}} />
```

Doing doesn't work nor does using CSS defined classnames. I am fairly new to React so I am sure there is a simple way to get around this.

EDIT: I found a workaround by wrapping the component in a div and then adding styling to that.

```
      <div style={{ marginBottom: '10px' }}>
        <EditTeamButtons showDelete={true} />
      </div>
```

Is this an appropriate way to do this?

Comment: `styles={{marginBottom: '10px'}}` Does EditTeamButtons have any code that uses the `styles` prop? If so, can you show it?

Comment: How about a `<br />` in between :D

Comment: @IrfanullahJan that technically works, haha. But kind of hard to adjust the amount of spacing I want with that...

Comment: @NicholasTower No, my EditTeamButtons does not use a styles prop in its code.

Comment: Yes, a wrapper container with appropriate style is acceptable, that was about to be my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For me the best way is to use **CSS grids**. You can add a class name to the container and after that you can specify the **gap** between the rows or columns.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

For example:
If you want to display [these two items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWwBk.png) next to each other with a space between them you can use the following styles:

```
.navigation-logo {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
    align-items: center;
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
}
```